# Stretch numpy vector to arbitrary length without interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with time series data with different sample frequencies.

I need to accurately stretch a set of 1d vectors of different lengths into a common arbitrary length. 
Values should be repeated rather than interpolated.

However, the number of repetitions should be rounded up or down appropriately throughout the target to arrive at a specific target length.

I can't seem to use np.repeat as it rounds off fractional numbers of repeats and the final length is always an exact multiple of repeats.

Basically I am looking for a function with roughly the following behavior:

```
stretch_func(np.array([1,2,4]), length=11)
```

out:`[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4]`

```
stretch_func(np.array(["A","B"]), length=11)
```

out: `["A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"]`

EDIT:
Looks like this functionality is not standard in numpy or pandas.  I went ahead and implemented this so here it is for anyone else that might need it:

```
def stretch_func(arr, length=1):
    repetitions = np.round(np.linspace(0,length,arr.shape[0]+1))[1:] - np.round(np.linspace(0,length,arr.shape[0]+1))[:-1]
    repeated = np.repeat(arr, repetitions.astype(np.int))
    return repeated
```

Comment: Have you considered making your own function? What type of Container is your data in before it is  an ndarray?

Comment: If the functionality doesn't already exist in numpy or pandas, I'll try to write something, but seems like stretching data like this might be a common use case, so I thought it might already exist.  Source data can be any commonly used container - numpy array, pandas series or a list.

Comment: So are you saying you did a quick browse through the docs found one thing that looked promising but decided to ask here for someone to finish the documentation search for you?

Comment: Why there are fewer `1` than `4` or `2`? That seems pretty arbitrary, why not fewer `4`?

Comment: Maybe you should [Answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of putting the answer in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out `repeat` can use a different number of repetitions for each element.  But choosing how to allocate those repetitions is ambiguous.  So it's not surprising that there isn't a packaged form of you function.

By way of illustration look at what `split` does in the reverse direction:

```
In [3]: arr = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4])
In [4]: np.split(arr,3)
...
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

`array_split` does the uneven split without complaint - but it short changes the last array, not the first as you chose to do:

```
In [5]: np.array_split(arr,3)
Out[5]: [array([1, 1, 1, 2]), array([2, 2, 2, 4]), array([4, 4, 4])]
```

Another point - calculating the number of repetions, even when uneven, is fast, with little dependency on the size of the array.  So there's no need to perform such calculations in compiled code.  Even if this kind of expansion was a common need (which I don't think it is), it would be implemented as a function similar to what you've written.  Look at the code for `array_split` to see how it handles edge cases.  (what if, for example, the desired length was less than the initial?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you could use [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and slice:

```
import numpy as np


def stretch_func(arr, length=1):
    reps = length // len(arr) + 1
    repeated = np.repeat(arr, reps)
    return repeated[-length:]

print(stretch_func(np.array([1,2,4]), length=11))
print(stretch_func(np.array(["A", "B"]), length=11))
```

**Output**

```
[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4]
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `repeat` is to select the indices using a linear space:

```
def stretch_func(arr, length=1, axis=0):
    idxs = np.round(np.linspace(0, arr.shape[axis] - 1, length)).astype(int)
    return arr.take(indices=idxs, axis=axis)
```

This would result in the following output:

```
print(stretch_func(np.array([1, 2, 4]), length=11))
[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4]

print(stretch_func(np.array(["A", "B"]), length=11))
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B']
```

This function supports stretching along any axis *as well as* "shrinking", e.g.:

```
print(stretch_func(np.arange(10), length=5))
[0 2 4 7 9]
```